# Erlang escript arguments

Tags: erlang, erlang-escript

I don't really understand how command line arguments work with escripts.  From the manpage, I understand that the arguments are passed as a list of strings to main/1.  How can I parse the arguments passed to main?

Consider the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
usage() ->
  io:format("Usage: ~s <port#>~n",[escript:script_name()]),
  halt(1).

main([]) ->
  usage();
main(Args)->
  io:format("Starting test server on port #~s~n",[Args]).
```

A simple test and all looks good with just one argument.

```
  ./test_server.erl 17001
   Starting test server on port #17001
```

What about if I pass in multiple arguments?

```
  ./test_server.erl 17001 8 9 abc
   Starting test server on port #1700189abc
```

That is not what I wanted.  I tried spliiting the string on the space character:

```
  ....
  ArgsList = string:tokens(Args, " "),
  io:format("Length: ~w~n",[length(ArgsList)]),
  ....
```

Yields
      Length: 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### length(L)

[`length/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#length-1) is a built in function that you can use just as is:

```
io:format("Length: ~p~n", [length(Args)])
```

### Args

`Args` is a list of strings. This call (using `~p` as format):

```
io:format("Starting test server on port #~p~n", [Args]).
```

Would yield the result:

```
./test_server.erl 17001 8 9 abc
Starting test server on port #["17001","8","9","abc"]
```

If you're using `~s`, Erlang interprets it as a string (or IO list, really) and that gets printed with all the element concatenated.

To print out all arguments one by one, try this instead of the `io:format/2` call:

```
[io:format("~s~n", [A]) || A <- Args].
```